# When editing a ruby file with includes/requires how can I open the file containing the method I am on?

Tags: filesystem, file-operations, include

I have a bunch of includes at the top of my file.

Then I use methods from the helpers throughout my file.

How can I have it so that when my cursor is on a method name my editor can (by some keystrokes) opens up that file and go to the method definition?

Comment: Check out http://ctags.sourceforge.net/ and `:h tags`.

Comment: You can't. Not 100% reliably anyway. Ruby is very dynamic, and Rails make quite a lot of use of that e.g. by defining methods with `CLASS_EVAL` and such, rather than just `def foo`...

Comment: ctags has been forked. The new maintained project is universal ctags. For some languages it really makes the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Use either `[d` or `[i`.

`:help include-search` is a built-in but sadly overlooked feature.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `gf`?

You may want to have a look at installing rails-vim if you haven't already.
http://vimawesome.com/plugin/rails-vim